# SQL Statement to pull records from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've trying to pull contacts from my email server's SQL database.
Need to pull the User, the Contact, and all the contacts details.

However, everything is in a separate table. 
This is what i'm running:

```
SELECT [Contacts].[ID]
  ,[Users].[LoginName]
  ,[Contacts].[JobTitle]
  ,[Contacts].[Company]
  ,[Contacts].[WebPageAddress]
  ,[Contacts].[FirstName]
  ,[Contacts].[LastName]
  ,[EmailAddresses].[Address]
  ,[EmailAddresses].[Name]
  ,[Addresses].[Name] 
  ,[Addresses].[Address1]
  ,[Addresses].[Town]  
  ,[Addresses].[County]
  ,[Addresses].[Country] 
  ,[Addresses].[Postcode]
  ,[PhoneNumbers].[Name] 
  ,[PhoneNumbers].[Number]


FROM [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts]
  INNER JOIN [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Users] 
  ON [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts].[Owner]=[WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Users].[ID]
  FULL OUTER JOIN [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[EmailAddresses]
  ON [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts].[ID]= [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[EmailAddresses].[OwnerID]
  FULL OUTER JOIN [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Addresses]
  ON [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts].[ID]= [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Addresses].[OwnerID]
  FULL OUTER JOIN [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[PhoneNumbers]
  ON [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts].[ID]= [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[PhoneNumbers].[OwnerID]
  order by [Contacts].[ID]
```

Since the Name field in the EmailAddress.Name contains either Email1 or Email2 I get a double return for each record. And the Address.Name field contains business, home or other I get a triple. and the PhoneNumbers.Name contains 4 field I get quadruple. Then you multiple that together an a list of 6000 contacts turns into several tens of thousands. Can't figure out how to write a loop or while statement. I think I have the logic just can't figure out the syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're only problem is duplicated records in your output, just add the word `DISTINCT` after `SELECT` and your result set will only contain unique records.

Comment: What is the purpose of FULL OUTER JOIN there? Also, if you're thinking in terms of loops or whiles, you're not thinking in SQL.

Comment: SOrry that was something I was testing, they should all be INNER JOIN. I tried adding DISTINCT after the SELECT and still get the same results.

Comment: What do you actually want in the `Address` and `Number` output columns? Is it okay to have the first matching email address, for example, or do you want to see all email addresses for a contact?

The real trick here is defining the problem. Think about what you actually want as a result in case of multiple email addresses and phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed set of values in each of the Name fields, then you can hard-code them into columns, so you get 1 row per contact with columns representing each 'flavour' of reference data. Something like below (I haven't added it for the 4 phone numbers as you didn't supply the possible values for Name in that case, but you should be able to get the drift):

```
SELECT [Contacts].[ID]
  ,[Users].[LoginName]
  ,[Contacts].[JobTitle]
  ,[Contacts].[Company]
  ,[Contacts].[WebPageAddress]
  ,[Contacts].[FirstName]
  ,[Contacts].[LastName]
  ,email1.[Address] as email1Address
  ,email2.[Address] as email2Address
  ,Address1.[Address1] as HomeAddress1
  ,Address1.[Town] as HomeAddressTown
  ,Address1.[County] as HomeAddressCounty
  ,Address1.[Country] as HomeAddressCountry
  ,Address1.[Postcode] as HomeAddressPostcode
  ,Address2.[Address1] as BusinessAddress1
  ,Address2.[Town] as BusinessAddressTown
  ,Address2.[County] as BusinessAddressCounty
  ,Address2.[Country] as BusinessAddressCountry
  ,Address2.[Postcode] as BusinessAddressPostcode
  ,Address3.[Address1] as OtherAddress1
  ,Address3.[Town] as OtherAddressTown
  ,Address3.[County] as OtherAddressCounty
  ,Address3.[Country] as OtherAddressCountry
  ,Address3.[Postcode] as OtherAddressPostcode
  ,[PhoneNumbers].[Name] 
  ,[PhoneNumbers].[Number]
FROM [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts]
  INNER JOIN [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Users] 
  ON [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts].[Owner]=[WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Users].[ID]
  FULL OUTER JOIN [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[EmailAddresses] email1
  ON [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts].[ID]= email1.[OwnerID] AND email1.[Name] = 'Email1'
  FULL OUTER JOIN [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[EmailAddresses] email2
  ON [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts].[ID]= email1.[OwnerID] AND email1.[Name] = 'Email2'
  FULL OUTER JOIN [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Addresses] Address1
  ON [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts].[ID]= Address1.[OwnerID] AND Address1.Name = 'Home'
  FULL OUTER JOIN [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Addresses] Address2
  ON [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts].[ID]= Address2.[OwnerID] AND Address2.Name = 'Business'
  FULL OUTER JOIN [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Addresses] Address3
  ON [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts].[ID]= Address3.[OwnerID] AND Address3.Name = 'Other'
  FULL OUTER JOIN [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[PhoneNumbers]
  ON [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[Contacts].[ID]= [WorkgroupShare].[dbo].[PhoneNumbers].[OwnerID]
  order by [Contacts].[ID]
```